# Calling a WCF service that uses ACS from a MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, acs, saml-2.0

I have a MVC website that uses ACS as an authentication provider.
The authentication process works well.
I want to call a WCF service that requires authentication and I want to pass an RST token but I don't know how to create it

Answer (score 0):

The key question is what identity is the WCF service expecting. If you can use an identity for the entire MVC site (a.k.a. "Trusted Subsystem"), then it is business as usual: you would need to get a token from an identity provider that the WCF trusts and that's it. ACS could be one, but it could be something entirely different too. It really depends on who owns the WCF service.

If, on the other hand, you want to flow to the WCF service the *original* user identity (that is the caller of the MVC site), then you are in a delegation scenario. This is possible, but it's often complex. Search for "Act As" (here's an article that talks a little bit about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517268.aspx).

In a nutshell, the MVC app would request a new token to the STS using as input the original token the user submited, with a special condition (the "Act As"). This condition signals the STS of the delegation.

As I said, this is a farily complex setup. Also (last I heard) ACS doesn't support "Act As" requests.

Comment: That's correct, ACS does not do ActAs. It sounds like the WCF service is a trusted subsystem, and if you call the WCF service in the context of your user's identity then you might try reusing the token from your MVC app (setting saveBootstrapToken true in web.config). If the service doesn't care which user is calling it then you might consider obtaining a new token from ACS using a service identity.